# Unable to upload video via YouTube link or direct upload

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

I'm attempting to add a video to my WordPress site (using the Divi theme), and no matter how I try to upload it I'm getting an error.

When I try to upload via YouTube, it gives me this error:

> Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found

When I try to upload directly to the site, it gives me this error:

> Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded
> successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.

The file I'm trying to upload to the site is 90MB, which doesn't exceed the maximum upload size that WordPress gives me (100MB), though maybe it exceeds some other maximum size somewhere else? Normally I would go into my cPanel in GoDaddy to check the wp files there, but my client only has a managed WordPress hosting account and I can't figure out how to get access to those files.

Comment: There is most likely a server cap, so you can't upload a video that large regardless of what WP is telling you. For the first issue, what link are you using to add to the Divi module? Did you get it from the URL, or the embed link? The embed link won't work and you need to use the `https://www.youtube.com/videoquerystringhere` URL.

Comment: @disinfor I tried swapping the URL and this time it at least showed me the preview of the video but it still reverted back to the original error

Comment: Divi can be finicky - you may need to reinstall/update Divi. Do you have any other plugins that need updating?